# Update field with count

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to count how many times an variable id value is repeated in field B of table 2, and update the value in field A of table 1 corresponding to the line which that variable id value is in the field B and the date.

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET Field_A = ( SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM  Table_2 
            WHERE Table_2.Field_B = 1 AND Table_2.Field_3='2015-04-04')
WHERE Table_1.Field_B = 1 AND Table_3.Field_3='2015-04-04'
```

Something like this

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET Field_A = ( SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM  Table_2 
            WHERE Table_2.Field_B = X AND Table_2.Field_3='xxxx-xx-xx')
WHERE Table_1.Field_B = X AND Table_3.Field_3='xxxx-xx-xx'

     Table 1                    Table 2     
Field_3 Field_1 Field_3         Field_4 Field_1 Field_3
      1    2    04-04-2015      200,00     1    04-04-2015
      2    3    04-04-2015      300,00     1    04-04-2015
      3    1    04-04-2015      150,00     2    04-04-2015
      1    1    05-04-2015      853,00     2    04-04-2015
      2    2    05-04-2015      200,00     2    04-04-2015
      3    1    05-04-2015      200,00     3    04-04-2015
      4    2    05-04-2015        3,00     1    05-04-2015
                                 40,00     2    05-04-2015
Field 1 - TransactionCount      900,00     2    05-04-2015
Field 2 - SessionID              35,00     3    05-04-2015
Field 3 - Date                   25,00     4    05-04-2015
Field 4 - TransactionSales      100,00     4    05-04-2015
```

Comment: Your initial statement is unclear when you say _corresponding to the line which that variable id value is in the field B_ . Please try to explain better, perhaps with an example using sample data.

Comment: I´ve changed my inicial statement. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Your question is still a mess. I tried hard to make sense of it and give you an answer, but there are too many things wrong with it. You talk about `Table_1` and `Table_2` but then throw in `Table_3`. You talk about updating `field_a` with the count or sum of `field_b` but then in your example tables you have `field_1` through `field_4`.  The sample dates provided are in the wrong format, `XX-XX-XXXX` not `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: And you still haven't clearly stated what you are trying to achieve. My best guess would be that you want the TransactionCount of Table_1 updated with the sum of the TransactionCounts from Table_2 which have the same date. But that leaves out the role of `SessionID`, and which column is the mysterious `Field_B` which apparently is supposed to be in both tables.  There is still no expected final result given for the sample data.

Comment: Vere confusing. Make sure all table and column names are correct! (Yes, it's columns, not fields...)